# Android: Hide/Display related views onClick

Tags: android, view

I have a dynamic list of subscriber buttons, each which have several dynamically generated card type buttons that are associated with the Subscriber. In my subscriber button onClick, I would like to display (or hide) the Card Type buttons, but I'm having an issue figuring out how to associate the group of cards with the particular subscriber. Here is what I have in my Onclick so far:

```
View.OnClickListener getSubscriberOnClick(final IdCardSubscriberButton subscriberButton)  {
    return new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Drawable icon;              
            if(subscriberButton.isExpanded() == false) {
                icon = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_id_card_close);                 
                subscriberButton.setExpanded(true);

                //Here's where I need to display the card Type buttons. How do I associate the 
                //card type buttons with this particular subscriber button?


            } else {
                icon = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_id_card_dropdown);
                subscriberButton.setExpanded(false);
            }               
            subscriberButton.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null,null,icon,null);

        }
    };
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setTag` to set the same tag for buttons in same group. And use `getTag` to set the visibility of tag with same group.

Comment: I like that idea, and I have assigned each subscriber and corresponding card types the same ID. How would I hide or display the card type buttons that have that tag, without also hiding the subscriber button, which also shares that tag?

Comment: Do you have he subcriber button id? Not tag id